# How to process large semi-structured json file

Tags: c#, json, stream

I've got to process large JSON files contain semi-structured data. e.g.

```
{
   stream: [
   {
      datastream: [
         ...
      ],
      schema: {
         name: "",
         version: ""
      }
   }, 
   {
      datastream: [
         ...
      ],
      schema: {
         name: "",
         version: ""
      }
   }]
}
```

I expect the json file to contain an object with a property "stream" which is a collection of objects with properties "datastream" and "schema". The "datastream" property can contain thousands of objects with arbitrary properties. What I actually need to do with is to process each element in the "datastream" collections and send them to another system. The other constraint is that when I'm sending the "datastream" elements I need to send along with them some of the attributes of the corresponding "schema".

The current approach relies on reading the entire file and deserializing the content into an object in memory and then processed with the processing. That works fine until the files reach a certain size. At the moment it starts to fail with OutOfMemoryException when the files exceed 300-400Mb. I also have to process files in excess of 1Gb in size. What is the best approach to solve this? My current attempt is to use JsonTextReader from (Json.NET) and process the json file one token at a time. That works well with respect to memory consumption. Just to make it clearing with this approach I do not have the entire content of the file in memory. At most I expect to have the current "datastream" element/entry along with the "schema". The current problem I'm facing with this approach is that it relies on the "schema" element appearing before the "datastream" if I want to enrich the "datastream" elements before forwarding them to another system. Does any of this make sense? What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: "At the moment it starts to fail with OutOfMemoryException when the files exceed 300-400Mb." - temporary fast fis while you rework the code: switch to 64 bit app, then you should have significantly higher limits.

Comment: @TomTom Thanks. What I've done so far is to change the platform target to x64 and the seems to work. Is this what you had in mind? At what point do you think I might starting getting into problems?

Comment: It is not about db. 32 bit apps are limited to 2-3 gb memory and that is fragemtned (so you can run out of allocation even way before). 64 bit apps have more space. This is not a "solution" but sometimes you just need a fast bandaid while working on the solution.